# "Your saying so don't make it so" meaning and grammar

Tags: grammar, meaning, american-english, conversation

What does "Your saying so don't make it so" in the following mean and is it grammatically valid?

> “You’re a coward and a pup. I’ll tell my big brother on you, and he can thrash you with his little finger, and I’ll make him do it, too.”
>
> “What do I care for your big brother? I’ve got a brother that’s bigger
> than he is—and what’s more, he can throw him over that fence, too.”
> [Both brothers were imaginary.]
>
> “That’s a lie.”
>
> “*Your* saying so don’t make it so.”

It's from [The Adventures of Tom Sawyer, chapter 1](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/74/74-h/74-h.htm#c1).

If it was "You're saying so, don't make it then/so.", I would say it means "You yourself are lying. So don't call me a lier.". But this structure is a little strange to me.

Could it be a proverb, the whole sentence?

Or maybe "Your saying" here means "What you say" and then he tells the other person *not to do so* (you yourself do not lie).

Or could it be some reductions/changes because of the dialect?

Comment: I think it's missing a comma to be more grammatically valid `Your saying so, don’t make it so`

Comment: @Tofandel A comma separating the subject from the verb would make it less grammatically correct.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would analyze it this way:

- **Your saying so**: Your action of saying that this thing is true
- **don't**: *doesn't*.  Using *don't* where standard English would use *doesn't*, like "It don't", is a dialect form that the speakers are using.
- **make it so**: make it true.

So put differently, it's "The fact that you say this thing is true does not make it true".  In this case, because the other speaker has said "That's a lie", the speaker is saying "It is not a lie just because you say it is."

Comment: This phrase reverberated in my head after reading this answer :)   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Say_it_ain%27t_so,_Joe_(disambiguation)

Comment: I , a native English speaker, first read Tom Sawyer when I was some single-digit age.  I didn't fully understand the meaning of this phrase until I was in my 30s.

Comment: 'Standard' English would use "does not" - the use of "doesn't" is itself an informal contraction.

Comment: @charmer "informal" doesn't mean "not standard".

Comment: @standon true - but that doesn't make a contraction 'standard' -